# How to execute local_setup.bash generated in cross-compilation environment?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'd like to know how to setup ROS2 environment on **arm** platforms. I thought simply executing `local_setup.bash` can get all the things ready. But it doesn't work.

I build up ROS2 in cross-compilation environment on **X86 PC**. After the building completes, I just copy the `install` directory to an **arm64** platform. I create the same directory on **arm** platform as that on **X86 PC**.
I execute `local_setup.bash` on arm but the ROS2 binary cannot be found. Besides, It seems that some modules are neither found. For example, I get an error show as below when I run ROS2 command.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
   File "./ros2", line 5, in <module>
      from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
      @_call_aside
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
       f(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
       working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
      ws.require(__requires__)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
      needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
      raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
  pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'ros2cli==0.4.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Could you please tell me how to adjust local_setup.bash on arm platform so I can execute it as on X86 PC?

Updates:

After set `AMENT_TRACE_SETUP_FILES`, the output of `local_setup.bash` is showed as below.

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/f053dea359c6a74f5bcaf9d4cf01b265

The output of `PYTHONPATH` is empty. The python library in use is:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-aarch64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

I follow [ros2-for-arm](https://github.com/ros2-for-arm/ros2/wiki/ROS2-on-arm-architecture) cross-compilation instructions to build ROS2.
The host **X86 PC** is Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64.

The **arm64** platform is a Hikey960 board with Ubuntu 16.04 aarch64 version.

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288000/how-to-execute-local_setup.bash-generated-in-cross-compilation-environment?/) by [davidhuziji](https://answers.ros.org/users/34542/davidhuziji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I download the latest code and force ROS2 to use Python3 on arm platform. Although there are still errors dumped, the demo can run.
Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [davidhuziji](https://answers.ros.org/users/34542/davidhuziji/) with karma: 16 on 2018-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0